# A message from a function getting multiply repeated

Tags: r, list, dataframe, function, loops

When `just_msg = TRUE`, my `foo` function should return the name of every `study.name` that it checks in my `data` and return two types of message:

**(1)** `"Error: 'study.name xxx' wrongly coded."`; and **(2)** `"No issues in 'study.name xxx' detected."`

So, for each unique `study.name`, we should see one of the above messages. However, I wonder why for some unique `study.name`, the message gets repeated multiple times?

Is there a fix? (*fully reproducible example is below*)

```
foo <- function(data, just_msg = TRUE){
  
  out <- lapply(split(data, data$study.name), function(x){
    pos_constant <- length(unique(x$post)) == 1L
    if (!pos_constant) {
      lapply(split(x, x$outcome), function(x_sub){
        mps <- x_sub[x_sub$control==TRUE,"mpre"]
        sps <- x_sub[x_sub$control==TRUE,"sdpre"]
        mps_constant <- length(unique(mps)) %in% c(1L,0L)
        sps_constant <- length(unique(sps)) %in% c(1L,0L)
        r <- !mps_constant || !sps_constant
        if (r) {
          
          if(just_msg) {
            
            message(sprintf("Error: '%s' wrongly coded.", x[,'study.name'][1]))
            
          } else {
            
            stop(sprintf("'%s' wrongly coded.", x[,'study.name'][1]), call. = FALSE)
            
          }
        } else if(just_msg) { 
          
          cat(sprintf("No issues in '%s' detected.\n",x[,"study.name"][1])) 
          
        } 
        
        return(r)
      })
    } else if(just_msg) { 
      
      cat(sprintf("No issues in '%s' detected.\n",x[,"study.name"][1])) 
      return(FALSE)
      
    }
  })

  if(just_msg) invisible(any(unlist(out)))
}

### EXAMPLE OF USE: ------------------------------------------------
data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m2/main/dat.csv")

foo(data, just_msg = TRUE)
```

Comment: if you change it to `message(sprintf("Error: '%s' wrongly coded with %s.", x$study.name[1], x_sub$outcome[1]))` would give unique message for each output

Comment: `o issues in 'Al_Ajmi' detected with 1.
No issues in 'Al.Ahm_Al.Jar' detected with 1.
No issues in 'Bitc_Knch_a' detected with 1.
No issues in 'Bitc_Knch_b' detected with 1.
No issues in 'Bitc_Knch_c' detected with 1.`

Comment: can you try the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the `stop/message` from inside the inner list, take out those `if/else if/else` statements outside the inner list.  Get the output of 'r' from the inner list, `unlist` the logical vector, then use `any` to test the condition for any TRUE cases from the inner list, then do the inner condition of `just_msg` or `else` ...

```
foo <- function(data, just_msg = TRUE) {
  out <- lapply(split(data, data$study.name), function(x) {
    pos_constant <- length(unique(x$post)) == 1L
    if (!pos_constant) {
            r_lst <- lapply(split(x, x$outcome), function(x_sub) {
              mps <- x_sub[x_sub$control == TRUE, "mpre"]
              sps <- x_sub[x_sub$control == TRUE, "sdpre"]
              mps_constant <- length(unique(mps)) %in% c(1L, 0L)
              sps_constant <- length(unique(sps)) %in% c(1L, 0L)
              r <- !mps_constant || !sps_constant
              
              return(r)
            })
            r <- any(unlist(r_lst))
            if (just_msg) {
                invisible(r)
            } else if (r) {
                if (just_msg) {
                  message(sprintf("Error: '%s' wrongly coded.", x[, 'study.name'][1]))
                  
                } else {
                  stop(sprintf("'%s' wrongly coded.", x[, 'study.name'][1]), call. = FALSE)
                  
                }
            } else if (just_msg) {
                cat(sprintf("No issues in '%s' detected.\n", x[, "study.name"][1]))
              
            }
            
            
            
          } else if (just_msg) {
            cat(sprintf("No issues in '%s' detected.\n", x[, "study.name"][1]))
            return(FALSE)
            
          } else NA
      })
     


}
```

-testing

```
foo(data, just_msg = TRUE)
No issues in 'Bitc_Yng_Cmrn' detected.
No issues in 'Dlsk_Krlr' detected.
No issues in 'Ev_Hart_StngKras' detected.
No issues in 'Fazio' detected.
No issues in 'Harts_Evans' detected.
No issues in 'Hartshorn' detected.
No issues in 'Karim_Nas.' detected.
No issues in 'Munoz' detected.
No issues in 'Nakazawa' detected.
No issues in 'Nusrat.etal.' detected.
No issues in 'Parreno' detected.
No issues in 'Polio_etal' detected.
No issues in 'Rahimi' detected.
No issues in 'Seiff_ElSak' detected.
No issues in 'Sob_Taybi' detected.
No issues in 'Sun' detected.
No issues in 'Trscott_Hsu' detected.
No issues in 'VanBe_Jng_Ken' detected.
No issues in 'Wagner' detected.
No issues in 'Wang' detected.
```

Comment: I expected `r` to be `TRUE` for `Error: 'Sheen_etal' wrongly coded.`, therefore, I expected `if(just_msg) invisible(any(unlist(out)))` should return `TRUE`, but why it currently doesn't?

Comment: @rnorouzian I find the Sheen_etal to return the error message when I filtered only that study.name

Comment: @rnorouzian can you please update what you expect as output because I was not sure what your expected was other than to remove the duplicate messages

Comment: Arun, when `just_msg==TRUE`, a `message` is returned for when `r == TRUE` not a `stop`. So, is there a way for `if(just_msg) invisible(any(unlist(out)))` to return a logical for each unique `study.name`. For `data` in my original question, `foo(data, just_msg = TRUE)`, should return a vector of all `FALSE` and only 1 `TRUE` for `study.name == "Sheen_etal"`. Is this clear?

Comment: Are you saying that `Error: 'Sheen_etal' wrongly coded.` should never be there?  It is an error because `r` is returning TRUE with `any(unlist(`

Comment: Arun, OP is saying that when 'just_msg = TRUE', 'invisible(any(unlist(out)))' must return a vector containing either TRUE or FALSE for each 'study.name' , BUT if you check, right now it returns NULL and some FALSE.

Comment: @Reza Because the `just_msg` is inside the `if(r) i.e. the just_msg is executed only if r is TRUE

Comment: @Reza when the data is large, it becomes a bit difficult to know how you want the ouptut.  Can you update your post with a small example and expected

Comment: Arun, can 'invisible(any(unlist(out)))' return the value of 'r' (which is a logical.) That's all.

Comment: @Reza It will only execute within the `if(r)` condition.  May be you need to take the `if(just_msg)` on the outer part then use `if(r)`

Comment: Yes, I simply need 'invisible(any(unlist(out)))' to return 'r' for each study.name.

Comment: @Reza check the ouptut

Comment: Arun, thanks, the `r` output is  correct. But messages are not shown for ALL `study.name`. So, we want messages to be shown for ALL `study.name`.

Comment: It is getting some confusing when you already coded the messages